# order by time and order by not null

Tags: php, mysql

my php + mysql code

```
//row mysql
$row_news = "SELECT `id`,`title_name`,`create_time`,`title_img` FROM `news` WHERE `status` = '1' ORDER BY  `create_time` DESC,`title_img` DESC";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($row_news);
$stmt->execute();
$row_news = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//Gropu by DATE row
foreach ($row_news as $key => $value) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $value["create_time"]);
    $row_news[$key]['date'] = $date;
}

foreach ( $row_news as $value ) {
    $group[$value['date']][] = $value;
}
```

I want to show

```
======================
2015-10-20
======================


[img] title-1......

[img] title-2......

[img] title-3......

title-4.....

title-5.....

title-6.....

======================
2015-10-19
======================

[img] title-1......

[img] title-2......

title-3.....
```

but...this sql can't do it.

I need group by date to partition content.

1. first DESC the `create_time`
2. show content row if title_img is not null....
3. and then show row of title_img is null

But, Now query anwer :

```
======================
2015-10-20
======================


[img] title-1......

title-4.....

[img] title-2......

[img] title-3......

title-5.....

title-6.....

======================
2015-10-19
======================

[img] title-1......

title-3.....

[img] title-2......
```

html demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m7c33nzL/1/

any suggest?

Comment: Your SQL is fine. Your PHP needs a little work, that's all.

Comment: All of the data you want will be returned on the query ... you should proccess data on your php code to show similar what you want ...

Comment: strawberry, thanks but can u give me any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your really problem is your query ...
your sql query is not good for sort date : you can use this sql query :

```
SELECT `id`,`title_name`,`create_time`,`title_img` FROM `news` WHERE `status` = '1' ORDER BY YEAR(`create_time`) DESC, MONTH(`create_time`) DESC, DAY(`create_time`) DESC,`title_img` DESC
```

after that, you can use this php code for handle your view :

```
<?php
//this for is for generate test data...
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
    $row_news[]=array(
        'create_time'=>time()+$i*36000,
        'title_img'=>"title image $i",
        'title_name'=>"title name $i"
    );
}
foreach ( $row_news as $value ) 
{

    $value['date'] = date("Y-m-d", $value["create_time"]);
    $group[$value['date']][] = $value;
}

foreach($group as $key=>$rows)
{
    echo "
    <br>======================<Br>
    $key<br>
    ======================<Br><br>";

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
          if(!empty($row['title_img']))
             echo $row['title_img'].'<Br>';
          echo $row['title_name'];
          echo '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

answer will be this :

```
======================
2015-10-20
======================

title image 0
title name 0

======================
2015-10-21
======================

title image 1
title name 1
title image 2
title name 2

======================
2015-10-22
======================

title image 3
title name 3
title image 4
title name 4

======================
2015-10-23
======================

title image 5
title name 5
title image 6
title name 6
title image 7
title name 7

======================
2015-10-24
======================

title image 8
title name 8
title image 9
title name 9
```

if you see anything else pls check your query and result of that ...

if you like can add result of db query in your question.

Comment: I mean if that row `title_img` is not null.  show these first....and then, show the other row of title_img is null

Comment: This could be updated with a usort before the second foreach to sort by whichever order you need.

Comment: @Sky you sorted array in your query .... (are you tested my code and get wrong answer ?)

Comment: Hi Roboticsexpert. Thanks very much your code. But my problem is many data is haven't title_img. And I need sort these rows after "exist title_img data" rows

Comment: @Sky can you add a sample query answer to your question ?

Comment: @Roboticsexpert your sql very Perfect for me ! thanks so much !!

Comment: still a problem pls look this img.http://postimg.org/image/iqe5rizrv/ , if that day not anyone title_img, will be sort the end

Comment: @Sky can you explain ?

Comment: in this photo http://postimg.org/image/iqe5rizrv/

2015-10-21 not anyone title_img...  sort all news of 2015-10-21 to the list end.

Comment: @sky can you run sql query in phpmyadmin and show me the answer ?

Comment: @Sky i ran that query on my local tbl ... i don't see any problem in that ...
http://tinypic.com/r/2d7cvgk/8

Comment: @Sky Why i don't see ordering priority on the head of column of title_img in your picture ? phpmyadmin always add number of priority ...

Comment: @Sky Can you export your table (data and structure) ?

Comment: Thanks, and create_time is UNIX timestamp int(10)  title_img varchar(255)